# Explanation for ternary operator in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have been going through nodeschool's regex-adventure and I have just completed the captures lesson.

My solution:

```
module.exports = function (str) {
    var x = /x=(\d+)/.exec(str);
    return x && x[1];
}
```

However the reference solution has

```
module.exports = function (str) {
    var x = /x=(\d+)/.exec(str);
    return x ? x[1] : null;
}
```

I am really just curious as to what the last line means.
`x` zero or one time `x[1]` but I am unaware of what `: null;` means in this instance. Does it mean "if not null"?

Answer (score 1):

It's [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
(condition ? expressionIfConditionIsTrue : expressionIfConditionIsFalse)
```

It's a shortcut for

```
if (expression) {
    // expressionIfConditionIsTrue   
} else {
    // expressionIfConditionIsFalse   
}
```

So if the regex founds a match then `x[1]` is returned and otherwise, the function returns `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you hear about ternary operator?

syntax:

```
condition ? true : false
```

So here,

```
return x ? x[1] : null;
```

If there is a match, it should return the characters which are fetched by the group index 1 else it should return null.